# File uploading works on local server but not web server

Tags: php, html, image, file, uploading

This exact code will work fine when uploading files on my local XAMPP server but uploading it to my web server this stops working. Other functions of the same project still work fine though.

```
    //Image Uploading
if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    $file_name = $file['name'];
    $file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $file['size'];
    $file_error = $file['error'];

    $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

    $allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'jpeg');

    if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed)) {
        $file_name_new = $username.'.png';
        $file_dest = '../images/'.$file_name_new;
        if($file_error > 0){
            echo "There was an error uploading this image! Try another.";
        } else {
            if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_dest)) {
                header("Location: ../user/editprofile.php?user=".$username);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HTML bit

```
                <h2>Profile Image</h2>
            <form action="editprofile.php?user=<?php echo $user; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="file">
                <input type="submit" value="Upload">
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I'd [pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to get the filename and file extension of the uploaded file. Secondly you should validate mimetype rather than extension by comparing what is in `$_FILES['userfile']['type']` against a list of mimetypes, for this situation you'll want to check for `['image/png', 'image/jpeg']` to prevent someone uploading something like a PHP script with a jpg extension. You also probably want to preserve the extension of the uploaded file rather than making them all png as this could cause unexpected errors.

With that out of the way the information will be inside `$file_error` to let you know exactly why the file isn't uploading. You will get back a [file error code](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) that will tell you what has gone wrong.

It will be one of these:

- `UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE` Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.
- `UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE` Value: 2; The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.
- `UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL` Value: 3; The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.
- `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE` Value: 4; No file was uploaded.
- `UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR` Value: 6; Missing a temporary folder. Introduced in PHP 5.0.3.
- `UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE` Value: 7; Failed to write file to disk. Introduced in PHP 5.1.0.
- `UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION` Value: 8; A PHP extension stopped the file upload. PHP does not provide a way to ascertain which extension caused the file upload to stop; examining the list of loaded extensions with phpinfo() may help. Introduced in PHP 5.2.0.

The most common on shared hosting is incorrect permissions on the file you're uploading to (value 7).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the uploaded directory permissions problem. Just change the directory permission mode like below:

```
chmod 777 uploaded_folder_name
```